# Cartesian product of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $a$ be a $2\times 1$ vector where each $i$th element $a_i$ taking value $1$ or $0$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all possible values of $a$, i.e. $\mathcal{A}:=\{(0,0), (1,1), (1,0), (0,1)\}$. 
Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of all subsets of $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. 
$$
\mathcal{B}:=\Big \{\{(0,0)\}, \{(1,1)\}, \{(1,0)\}, \{(0,1)\}, \{(0,0),(1,1),(1,0),(0,1) \}, \{(0,0),(1,1)\}, \{(0,0),(1,0) \}, \{(0,0),(0,1)\}, \{(1,1),(1,0)\}, \{(1,1),(0,1) \}, \{(0,1),(1,0) \} \Big \}
$$
Let $B_r,B_t,B_s$ be three sets of $\mathcal{B}$ and let's take their cartesian product, e.g. if $B_r=\{(0,0) \}$, $B_t=\{(1,1),(0,1) \}$ and $B_s=\{(0,0)\}$ their cartesian product is $C_{r,t,s}=\Big \{\Big((0,0),(1,1),(0,0)\Big),\Big((0,0),(0,1),(0,0)\Big) \Big\}$.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of all possible $C_{r,t,s}$.

Now let $d$ be a $3\times 2$ matrix with each $ij$th element taking value $1$ or $0$. Let's write $d$ as $\Big ((d_{11},d_{12}),(d_{21},d_{22}),(d_{31},d_{32})\Big )$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the set of all possible values of $d$ and let $\mathcal{E}$ be the collection of all subsets of $\mathcal{D}$.

**Question: is $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{E}$? If this not the case which is the relation between them?**

My intuition is that they are not equivalent and that each $E \in \mathcal{E}$ is a subset of a $C\in \mathcal{C}$ but I'm not sure. For example I think that the set $E=\Big \{\Big((1,0),(1,0),(1,0) \Big),\Big((0,0),(0,0),(0,0) \Big) \Big \}$ cannot be written as a Cartesian product  of sets in $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: That's a peculiar use of the term "vector" here. I take it that you've been programming for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ has 4 elements. $B$ has $2^4=16$ elements. $C$ has $16\times16\times16=2^{12}$ elements.

$D$ has $2^6=64$ elements. $E$ has $2^{64}$ elements. $E$ is a lot bigger than $C$.

Comment: Can I ask you whether it is possible to say that: all sets in $E\C$ (remainder of $E$ when $C$ subtracted) are subsets of at least a set of $C$?